# REST API and Manage Package

Tags: rest-api, json, security-token

We are going to be implementing a package for several clients and there are a few things we are wondering on how to accomplish this, I was hoping someone could give me a hand here.

Let me explain the situation. 
We are going to add a functionality that will be consuming JSON using REST to execute several calculations. We have the interface and the
call-outs are just fine, so we are getting the responses, happy campers here.

In order to obtain an access token and after that being able to connect to the JSON endpoint we need several parameters, **client_id** and **client_secret**.

Every client has a different one and we need to be able to add their unique keys to the installation in order to make sure they get access and that way allows them to make calls-outs using the REST code built in the package.

So the question is, there is a way to insert those key (**client_id** and **client_secret**) through the installation process?

They need to be unique for several reasons, one of them is that on the endpoint the can track who and how many times a client connects to their APIs by using the new functionality.

Any ideas will be great on these.

Comment: Two questions : Does the customer know these parameters or do you have to generate it ? How do you plan to store those sensitive data ?

Comment: we have those parameters for existing clients.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a VisualForce page with a form letting the installing user put this information, then your controller can store it wherever you want. 
When you deploy your app, on the "Upload package" page, you have to specify (section "Post Install Instructions") that you want this page to be displayed after install.

However if you have many tests and your install process is long, the page won't be displayed so the customer will have to the package page in setup, he'll find there the link to the page (or you can of course documentate it).